# how to capture the exit status of capture calling another perl script within a perl script and if it fails it should die

Tags: perl, unix, exit, secure-crt

I've just started using Perl 5.26 on secure-CRT and i wrote a Perl script that capture calls multiple Perl scripts.

```
 my @secondCommand = capture("perl clientquery.pl -r $cid -l test.log -is $sqlFile");
```

I was wondering how can I capture the exit status of each capture calling and if it fails how can i make the original script die.

Comment: Where does the `capture()` function come from? Maybe it already returns the exit status somewhere? Or maybe it sets `$?` ?

Comment: what do you exacltly mean? can you be more specific?

Comment: use IPC::System::Simple qw(system capture);

Comment: capture from IPC::System::Simple will already die by default if the command fails or returns a nonzero exit status (this is the "simple" part). You can specify that it not die on certain exit codes (or any exit code), see [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple#Exit-values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IPC::System::Simple provides `$EXITVAL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple#$EXITVAL), which captures the exit code of commands run via `capture` and the other functions.

> The exit value of any command executed by IPC::System::Simple can
>   always be retrieved from the `$IPC::System::Simple::EXITVAL` variable:
>
> This is particularly useful when inspecting results from capture,
>   which returns the captured text from the command.
>
> ```
> use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture $EXITVAL EXIT_ANY);
>
> my @enemies_defeated = capture(EXIT_ANY, "defeat_evil", "/dev/mordor");
>
> print "Program exited with value $EXITVAL\n";
> ```
>
> `$EXITVAL` will be set to -1 if the command did not exit normally (eg,
>   being terminated by a signal) or did not start. In this situation an
>   exception will also be thrown.

Comment: Top Lad, Thanks!